# How do I extract "Grade" value from the 2nd column of excel sheet

Tags: excel

[image: Excel Image]

As you can see the column that says "Grade" is blank. What I am try to do is pull the letter from the 2nd column only for students 3,8,and 10, and put their grades in the empty "Grade" column. What function can help me do that. I have 1000 data points, and I need to do that. This is just a sample I created.

Thanks!!

Comment: `=LOOKUP(D2,$B2:$B$11,$C2:$C$11)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use an `INDEX MATCH` formula:

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(D2,A:A,0))
```

Comment: Just FYI @Master, this will return the same as `=Vlookup(D2,A:B,2,false)` in  your example.